# Using Multiple Databases in Silverlight wtih Entity Framework

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

I am asking the same question in a different way in hopes I can get a few ideas this time.

My Silverlight uses RIA Services and Entity Framework.  I have a tree control on my UI with any number of nodes.  Each node is a project and the data for that project could be on one of many servers.  The database is also unique to that project.

When the users selects a node, I know what server and database the info is on, but how do I dynamically create the connection string used by the DomainService?

I have tried everything I can think of.  It seems as though because I cannot keep my connection strings in my web.config file, I cannot use Entity Framework.

Thanks in advance...

-Scott

Comment: What does prevent you from using WCF services through SOAP? Or WCF Data Services? I worked with them and these technologies allow using a server adress as a constructor parameter.

Comment: It gets a bit more complicated when using Ria services.  The DomainService gets converted to a DomainContext on the client side.  The DomainService allows 3 constructors and that's it.  Because it gets related to the client via generated code, there is no way to add a constructor.  Also, the CreateObjectContext in the DomainService gets called the very first time you reference the DomainService.  This is the last chance to make changed to the connection string.  I did find a solution that I am posting below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to my problem.  I posted it on another version of the same question here:  [Silverlight Entity Framework Dynamic Connection String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350434/silverlight-entity-framework-dynamic-connection-string/4357739#4357739)

-Scott